# Как сделать position absolut не зависимый от родителя relative

Tags: html, css

Как сделать что бы .background-mask закрасил весь сайт а .buttons стал ровно по центру этого элемента

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-mask {
  background-color: #222;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="block">

    <div class="background-mask">

      <div class="buttons">
        <span>Test!</span>

        <p>test</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: как-то так, что ли? => https://jsfiddle.net/9Lpryqof/

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе нужно именно с этой конструкцией html-тэгов, то вот решение (смотреть на весь экран):

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-mask {
  background-color: #222;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.background-mask {
    background-color: #222;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 150px);
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.buttons {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="block">

    <div class="background-mask">

      <div class="buttons">
        <span>Test!</span>

        <p>test</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Если надо зафиксировать то пишем такой CSS:

```
.background-mask {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100vw;
    /* margin-left: calc(-50vw + 150px); */
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Получаем:

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-mask {
  background-color: #222;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.background-mask {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100vw;
    /* margin-left: calc(-50vw + 150px); */
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.buttons {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
Если тебе нужно именно с этой конструкцией html-тэгов, то вот решение (смотреть на весь экран):

body {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-mask {
  background-color: #222;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.background-mask {
    background-color: #222;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 150px);
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.buttons {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
<body>

  <div class="block">

    <div class="background-mask">

      <div class="buttons">
        <span>Test!</span>

        <p>test</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Отлично я примерно так же реализовал но вот при скроле внизу остается место

Comment: @Михаил Волков Ответ то правильный. У вас вопрос кривой: «Как сделать position absolut не зависимый от родителя relative», получается позицию нужно фиксированную. Пишите правильно вопросы. Если надо фиксированный, то читайте обновленный ответ, убираем margin, меняем позицию на фиксированную.